# Deleted message still flagged in chat

Tags: bug, chat, flags

In Stack Overflow chat, I just see flags in the [Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) chat room where one user was swearing and then someone flagged. But after the post is removed, the flag is still shown after the message

> [image]

but except this every time flag disappear with the deletion of the message

Comment: Worth mentioning - I think there is a general feeling in chat that the flagging system (not the for mod one) is broken.

Comment: Ah, yes, the Schrödinger's Flag issue. Is it alive? Is it dead? Has it been dealt with? Is it still there? woooOO000oooOOO000OOoo